# How to know container of TapGesture Recgoinizer in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to know the container of an `UITapGestureRecognizer` in Swift

For example, if I put a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `View1`

When `UITapGestureRecognizer` action is triggered, how do I know that `View1` is the container of that `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: The UIGestureRecognizer docs are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/view Notice it says "view: The view the gesture recognizer is attached to." Gosh, what might that be about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your selector that you pass for the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to call, `sender` will be the `gestureRecognizer`, and `sender.view` will be the view the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is attached to.